# Swift UI: relationship between the sheet and list views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have the following sample view to try the behavior of the `sheet` in `SwiftUI`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Word: Identifiable, Codable {
 var id: String
}

struct TestView: View {
  @State var isPresented = false
   var items: [Word] = [Word(id: "Test1"),
                     Word(id: "Test2"),
                     Word(id: "Test3")]
 var body: some View {
   NavigationView {
     List {
       ForEach(items) { word in
          Text(word.id)
     }
   }
  .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
    SomeTestViewInsideTheSheet(action: {
        self.isPresented = false
      })
    .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 400, alignment: .center)
    }
  .navigationBarTitle(Text("My Title"))
   }
  }
}

struct SomeTestViewInsideTheSheet: View {
   var action: ()->()
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
        Text("Test View")
        Button("Dismiss") {
            self.action()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I just want to understand: what is the relationship between the list and sheet ? why should I tie the sheet with the list using the `.sheet` at the end of the list ?
And what is the proper way to show the sheet in this example.

p.s. the sample code compiles fine in an XCode project but not in a Playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why should I tie the sheet with the list using the `.sheet` at the end of the list ?

You are not tying the sheet with the list. You are not adding `.sheet` at the end of the list either. Read your code again! You are adding `.sheet` at the end of `NavigationView`.

So it's the `NavigationView` (the "top level" view object) that presents a new top level view as a sheet. And this is not actually "tying" anything. As you can see, clicking on the list items don't do anything. `.sheet` here really just serves as a "declaration", that there is a sheet that I will present.

> And what is the proper way to show the sheet in this example.

To actually present the sheet, you need to set `isPresented` to true. You can set it to true at any time. But seeing how you have a `List`, I'm guessing you want to set it to true when an item is selected. You can use `Button`s instead of `Text`s for selectable list items:

```
 List {
   ForEach(items) { word in
      Button(word.id) {
        self.isPresented = true
      }
 }
```

Comment: what's the difference between declaring the .sheet at the end of the NavigationView and the at the end of List ? both compiles successfully.

Comment: @JAHelia Yeah, but if you put it at the end of `List`, you can't present the sheet a second time. You will get a warning saying that you are trying to present something which has been presented already. I am quite new to SwiftUI too, so I don't know _exactly_ what's going on. But it makes more sense for the top level view to present another top level view, doesn't it?

Comment: yeah, it's more reasonable to add it at the top level view than into a nested view, and I can see many questions on SO about problems presenting the sheet the second time.